# Automatically convert short array syntax to long (traditional) in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

How to automatically convert short array syntax to long(traditional) in PhpStorm?

I used the feature "Code -> Inspect Code" in PhpStorm and then one by one click convert short syntax to long.

Inspect code

[image: First inspect code]

Manually convert

[image: Manually convert]

**There has to be a way to automate this job? Are there macros in PHPStorm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. If it was a failing inspection, there would be a "Fix all problems in file" option in the submenu. Intentions don't have this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

go to Settings(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)-> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Code Conversion -> Array Declaration Style -> tick Force short declaration style Checkbox.

press OK -> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> -> voila

Comment: This is the long to short version. The original question was the other way around

Answer (score 3):

Bartosz is right. To avoid manual work you can use [Short Array Syntax Converter](https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter) tool with [revert](https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter#revert) (short into long array syntax) option. But be aware, that

> Reverting has not yet been thoroughly tested, so use with extreme
>   percaution!

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried setting PHP version to 5.3 and then only search for this via Inspect code? Don't have PhpStorm installed anymore.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.